# Find files to find multiple instances of the same code with Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, regex, html, find

I might have inserted `<meta charset="UTF-8">` twice in some HTML files, and there are too many of them to check manually.

Is there a regular expression I can use with Notepad++ to search for files that have `"utf-8"` appearing more than once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex

```
utf-8.*utf-8
```

in the "Find in Files" dialogue. Make sure to check "Regular expression" and ". matches newline" in the Search Mode. Under "Filters" you can define the type of file you want to search in and in "Directory" choose the dir where your files are in.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!  I've also found another method and will describe it in a separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

A "Find in Files" search in Notepad++ will tell you how many results are in how many files, for example 142 results in 148 files.  From that number you can calculate the number of dupe entries.  The search results can be copied to a new file, and from there you can run a search for '2 hits' '3 hits' etc, until all dupes are eliminated.